# Overlay element on toolbar

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to impose a Cardview element on the toolbar. And at the stage of previewing everything is displayed correctly. However, after compiling, Cardview is under the toolbar. What could be the problem? Thanks you!

Screenshot.
It should be.:
[image: It should be.]

Screenshot.
How come.:
[image: How come.]

API 22. Here and There.

My project structure: file "activity_documents" (there are left-navigation) -> file "app_bar_document" (there are toolbar) -> file "content_documents"

My code:
"activity_documents":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_documents_type"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_documents_type"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_documents_type_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

"app_bar_documents":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".DocumentsTypeActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/back_toolbar_documents"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_documents"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                android:text="Документы"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        <!--android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"-->

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_documents_type"/>
    <!--<include layout="@layout/content_doc"/>-->

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin" />

</FrameLayout>
```

"content_documents"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".DocumentsTypeActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_documents_type">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardView_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/background_light"
                app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
                app:cardElevation="4dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_documents_multipass" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="MultiPass.One"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            app:fontFamily="sans-serif-black" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Ваш международный \n документ"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

DocumentActivity:

```
package com.multipassone;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class DocumentsTypeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_documents_type);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

}
```